# Rank of matrix $AB$ when $A$ and $B$ have full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix with rank $n$, and let $B$ be a $n \times p$ matrix with rank $p$. Calculate the rank of matrix $C=AB$.

---

The rank of a matrix is the number of linearly independent rows.

Comment: answered in question. A*B is just a matrix multiplication

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The conditions from the hypothesis imply that $m\ge n\ge p$. One knows that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\le \min(m,p)=p$. On the other side, from [Sylvester Rank Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29) we get $p=n+p-n\le \operatorname{rank}(AB)$, so $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=p$.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I deleted my post.

Comment: What if $A$ does not have a full column rank? Does rank($AB$)=rank($A$)?

Answer (score 8):

The conditions imply (as pointed out in YACP's +1 answer) that $m\ge n\ge p$. Another way of reaching the desired conclusion is that consequently the underlying linear mappings (the linear mappings that have the given matrices w.r.t to natural bases)
$A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ and $B:\mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ are both injective. Therefore the composition $AB$ is also injective. Therefore its rows are linearly independent. Therefore $AB$ has full rank, too.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $M$ is an $r\times s$ matrix, $\varphi_M$ denotes a linear operator related to $M$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\varphi_M:k^s&\to k^r\\
x&\mapsto Mx
\end{align}

Since $\operatorname{rk}(A)=n$, we have $\dim(\operatorname{im}(\varphi_A))=n$. By [Rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), $\dim(\ker(\varphi_A))=0$, therefore $\varphi_A$ is injective. Likewise, $\varphi_B$ is injective, hence $\varphi_C=\varphi_{AB}=\varphi_A\circ\varphi_B$ is injective, thus $\dim(\ker(\varphi_C))=0$, and $\dim(\operatorname{im}(\varphi_C))=p$, so $\operatorname{rk}(C)=p$.