# rank of $AB$ when $B$ has full column rank?

Tags: matrix-rank

Suppose $B$ has a full column rank. Does it hold that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$?

---

I found a [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272049/rank-of-matrix-ab-when-a-and-b-have-full-rank). But it does not prove or disprove the above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is only true for $B$ square otherwise, as counterexample, we can consider $A_{n\times n} $ full rank and $B_{n\times 1} $ such that rank$(AB)=1$

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\1&-1 \end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix} \implies AB=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$

which leads to rank$(AB)=1$ with rank$(A)=2$.

Comment: why $Av$ does not equal to 0?

Comment: @mxdxzxyjzx I've revised with a simpler way to see that, indeed the first one wasn't completely correct and enlightening.